# How to select the right config file with Gradle?

Tags: plugins, build, gradle, copy, config

My app has a general project structure like so:

```
src/main/groovy
    <Groovy files>
src/main/resources
    config.dev.xml
    config.qa.xml
    config.live.xml
build.gradle
gradle.properties
settings.gradle
```

In my Gradle build I use the [Shadow Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to produce a "fat JAR" (standalone executable) by running:

```
gradle clean build shadowJar
```

This produces a new `build` directory like so:

```
src/main/groovy
    <Groovy files>
src/main/resources
    config.dev.xml
    config.qa.xml
    config.live.xml
build.gradle
gradle.properties
settings.gradle
build/
    distributions/
        myapp-standalone.jar
```

I would like the ability to specify which config file should be copied to this `build/distributions` directory, and I would like to specify this in the command itself. So something like:

```
gradle clean build shadowJar -Pconfig=dev
```

or:

```
gradle clean build shadowJar copyLive
```

etc. But I'm new to Gradle and not sure what the conventions are here, or what the best approach would be. The end result would be (in the case of selecting `config.dev.xml`), a build that produces:

```
build/
    distributions/
        myapp-standalone.jar
        config.dev.xml
```

Same for QA, LIVE, etc...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) you can set properties with `gradle clean build shadowJar -Pconfig=dev` and then access it with `config`.
When you want to read it, you can do something like this:

```
if (project.hasProperty('config') && config == dev) {
    println config
}
```

Comment: Thanks @The End (+1) - however in that link I don't see any mention of an `ext.config` property or closure. Can you be more specific or provide an example? Thanks again!

Comment: you can leave out the `ext` and use it directly. Also I added an example how you can use your property.

Answer (score 0):

try to use as 'The End' said projectProperty.

I think better option for you will be to put xml configuration inside jar. I guess that you want to have another config file in case of dev, production or etc. environment.

The structure would  look like :

```
build/
    distributions/
        myapp-standalone.jar
                  src/...
                  resources/
                      config.dev.xml
```

and exaple how to get such effect:

```
jar{
    def config = 'dev'

    if (project.hasProperty('config')) {
        config = project.getProperty('config')
    }

    from ('src/main/resources/*config*.xml'){
        into 'resources'
    }
```

}

if you dont want to have config file in jar, just remove tag 'jar' and write some task for example:

```
task copyConfigFiles{
  // here put your copy code
}

jar.dependsOn copyConfigFiles
```